# Assign a string of html.erb or multiple line with .val() in Rails js.erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Trying to assign a value to an textarea element with `jquery` .val() in Rails 4.2 `js.erb`:

```
$('#argument_value').val("<%=arg_value%>");
```

This line works when `arg_value` is a simple text, such as "test". However when `arg_value` is multi line string (as below) or Ruby `html.erb` string, it does not assign:

```
 arg_value = "member do
    get :event_action
    patch :acknowledge
    patch :submit
end

collection do
   get :list_open_process
end"
```

The program does not know before hand the detail of text string it is getting. The `arg_value` can be a complex Ruby `.html.erb` file or a multiple line text string. How to make `jquery.val()` work in these situation?

Comment: To the guy who downvoted this post, do you know the answer? Or you don't know the answer and don't understand the question as well. then why did you downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `j` (alias for `escape_javascript`):

```
$('#argument_value').val("<%= j(arg_value) %>");
```

Comment: Totally forgot about j! Tried simple_format and h. thanks.